# CSH - arithmetic operation in a case

Tags: unix, math, csh

how to make this work: total count is 5, but then the min script starts at 0, so when calling it i'd like to limit it by the number in the scripts, which is 4 max. but then total count is 5.

```
count = 5
 case "[0-($count - 1)]":
   set count = $2
       echo -n "starting $listener$count $inputname..."
   breaksw
```

still, its starting script5, even though there is only script4 max.

Help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to use a regular expression in your case statement?

Comment: hi, currently im using [0-$count] and it seems to work. but then I wanted to change the range from 0 to ($count minus 1). just wondering if i can do an arithmetic operation in my case statement?

Answer (score 0):

> just wondering if i can do an arithmetic operation in my case
>   statement?

Unfortunately you can't; you have to do the arithmetic beforehand, e. g.

```
: spaces are needed :
@ max = $count - 1
...
 case "[0-$max]":
```